# 3D SplitScreen XNA - How to Draw 2 players in same Viewport with 2 cameras

Tags: 3d, xna, camera, models, viewport

I'm new on this website, however I tried  to do the best I could to research an answer to my question on the web.. but still I could not find anything that was really helpfull.

So here is the thing, I'm trying to a simple 3D car game, and I'm just begining.  I am currently working on the splitscreen and the problem I encountered was this:

I actually CAN see both "ships" (one in the right viewport, one in the left), but I can't seem to find a way to Draw both ships in both viewports, but with their own camera.  So yes I've also created two different chase cameras, one for the left viewport and one for the right.

Can anyone guide me in any way ? If you need any code to help you answer, I'll paste it and explain (only problem is that it's in french).

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated answer from discussion:*

It sounds like you need to change your constructor to accept not only the "target" car but also all other cars on the track. e.g. View(targetCar, allOtherCars)

I'd suggest: Create a new method that takes the camera position / translation and render all the cars from that perspective. Then, in the draw method, call the new method with camera associated with the current viewport.

*Original Answer:*

I'm having trouble understanding exactly the effect you're after but on the assumption that's just a variation on the split screen idea, here's one way to tackle the problem:

In the game initalisation:

1. Create two render targets - One for each player's screen

In the Draw Method:

1. Set the graphics target to player one's render target, render the scene from player one's camera perspective... and then do the same for player two.
2. Draw both player's render targets to the screen.

If you're not aware of RenderTargets then the following example from Microsoft may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434402.aspx

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explain my point correctly.  What I mean is that I Have 2 viewports. One on the left, one on the right. 
Next, I have one ship in the right viewport that moves with it's ChaseCamera, and one ship in the left viewport that also moves with it's Chase Camera.  What I'm looking for, is to be able to see the "left" ship in the right ship's camera. But from what i understood, Viewports are like different worlds, so they can't see each other.

Comment: Is the problem that your chase cameras are too close to the cars ... or that when you render each view, only one car is appearing (even though each camera is far enough away to be able "see" both cars)?

Comment: It's  that when I render each view only one car is appearing, because in my Draw method I draw each ship depending on the viewport it received in it's constructor!

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your constructor to accept not only the "target" car but also all other cars on the track. e.g. View(targetCar, allOtherCars)

Comment: That's a good idea, but in my draw method which looks like this
http://pastebin.com/SZppiCTz   

I draw the model depending on the Camera that is associated to it (also received in the constructor).. but for the "allOtherCars", should I also draw them depending on the same camera ? (If you need explanation for the code, don't hesitate)

Comment: I'd suggest: Create a new method that takes the camera position / translation and render all the cars from that perspective. Then, in the draw method, call the new method with camera associated with the current viewport.